# Is it possible to disable the clipboard service?

Tags: copy-paste

I would like to replace the native clipboard functionality with a third-party app and I want to disable the stock clipboard to prevent myself from accidentally storing things there out of habit. Is there a way to disable the clipboard service on an unrooted device running Android 10?

Comment: As a general rule, you can't disable any stock feature unless it is an app & clipboard isn't an app//If you root your device, there *may*  be ways to disable it or flash a custom ROM that let's you do this

Comment: @beeshyams Ok, that's what I figured, but I was hoping there was a trick or something. My issue is that the clipboard is shared across different profiles on my phone and I want it to be separated.

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible//adding your motive to the question by [edit]ing may help getting solutions